# slicing an string after a word in python

Tags: string, slice, python-3.8

So my issue is I have a string/URL:

```
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOoMXn3N5ME&list=PL5E1B8DFA8A07A9FA"
```

And I want to trim the

```
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOoMXn3N5ME&list="
```

Leaving only the playlist Id which is:

```
"PL5E1B8DFA8A07A9FA"
```

I know I could do something with slicing and indexing like

```
string = string[0:49]
```

but for my application the input link/URL will vary in size
and the playlist id or video id will change the length of the string. So how can I trim this string directly after the

```
list=
```

Possibly needed resources:
python: 3.8.10
pip: 20.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to slice the string and handling all sorts of potential edge cases, I'd use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```py
from urllib.parse import *
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOoMXn3N5ME&list=PL5E1B8DFA8A07A9FA"
list_id = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['list'][0]
```

Comment: Perfect response may god bless your soul.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to import anything.

```
link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOoMXn3N5ME&list=PL5E1B8DFA8A07A9FA"
index = link.find('list')
ID = link[index+5:-1]
```

I used the find() method to find the index of the word 'list'. Then I did the rest from there.